# Access denied when requesting Oauth2 token from Azure AD with Authorization code flow

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, scope, token

We are developing an application with a frontend and a backend. The backend should be accessed via Rest API with an OAuth2 token. Authorization provider is Azure AD.

In Azure we created 2 app registrations. One for the API, one for the client app. The API registration defines 3 scopes (Read, Write, Delete). The client app registration has delegated permission for these scopes.

We are requesting tokens with the clientID and clientSecret from the client app registration.

When requesting a token for a certain scope, after login and approval of permission grant prompt, I just get an access denied error. Does my user need any additional permission in Azure AD to grant permission for the requested scope?

As a workaround I could add the client app as an 'Authorized client application' in the API registration for all three scopes. But then all three scopes are always returned in the JWT under 'scp' regardless of the scope I am requesting and the user does not see the permission grant prompt anymore. Not sure if I want this. I would rather understand how to solve the access denied.

Comment: What does your scope in request look like?

Comment: For example: api://myApiName/Read. This is exactly the scope name I defined in the API registration under 'Expose an API'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that user consents are not allowed in my organization's AD tenant. (Enterprise Applications -> Consent and Permission -> User Consent Settings.)